# UIView different lengths on all sides

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Is it possible to make a UIView with the sides all different lengths? Would I have to override drawRect in order to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `UIView` objects have a rectangular frame. But a view can appear in any shape depending on how it is implemented. Implementing the `drawRect:` method to draw the desired shape is certainly an option.

You may also have to deal with touch events if you only want the events to register within the apparent shape of the view.